# Ipython console not returning output of summary()

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

so i am trying a multiple linear regression model,when i call for the command to see the summary of the model.Using this command.

```
#backward elimination 
x_opt=x[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
reg_ols=sm.OLS(endog=y,exog=x_opt).fit()
reg_ols.summary()
```

The Ipython console is not showing the summary statistic.Instead i am getting this output.

[image: ipythone console output]

**How can i get the summary statistic?.I am using python 3.6, spyder version 3.2.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the last line with

```
print(reg_ols.summary())
```

You forgot to mention you were using [Statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html). Looking at the documentation, `summary()` returns a string, rather than printing it, so you need to do the printing yourself.

Comment: actually  i am new to spyder, executing using f9 and the problem is resolved. I was using the green play button on top for execution.